# How to pass gradle property of parent project to logback.xml in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have this projects structure:

```
- parent-project
  - build.gradle
  - gradle.properties
  - child-project
    - build.gradle
    - src
      - main
        - java
        - resources
          - application.properties
          - logback.xml
```

This is the parent build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    apply plugin: 'maven'

    group = 'com.test'

    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url nexusRepo
            credentials {
                username = nexusUsername
                password = nexusPassword
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    
    uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                repository(url: nexusRepo) {
                    authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

uploadArchives.enabled = false
```

my gradle.properties of the parent project contains among others this:

```
version=0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

This is the child-project build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.0.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'groovy'
    id 'war'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

dependencies {
    //spring boot related dependencies
    ...
    implementation "com.xm.logback:jLogbackGelfAppender:1.1.0"
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.30'
    implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
    implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-core', version: '1.2.3'
    implementation group: 'net.logstash.logback', name: 'logstash-logback-encoder', version: '6.3'
    ...
    //testing related dependencies
}
```

This is the child-project application.properties:

```
prop.testserver.computer-name=${COMPUTERNAME}
...

# graylog properties
graylogHost=host.com
graylogPort=555
graylogSourceId=app_id_dev
```

The reason I am posting the prop.testserver.computer-name property is because I tried using gradle resourceProcess and got an error concerning this property.

This is my logback.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE configuration>

<configuration>
  <contextName>${graylogSourceId}</contextName>
  <jmxConfigurator/>

  <springProperty scope="context" name="graylogHost" source="graylogHost"/>
  <springProperty scope="context" name="graylogPort" source="graylogPort"/>
  <springProperty scope="context" name="graylogSourceId" source="graylogSourceId"/>

  <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
  </appender>

  <appender name="GELF" class="com.xm.logback.GelfAppender">
    <server>${graylogHost}</server>
    <port>${graylogPort}</port>
    <protocol>TCP</protocol>
    <includeSource>true</includeSource>
    <includeMDC>true</includeMDC>
    <additionalFields>
      application=${graylogSourceId}
    </additionalFields>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <pattern>%m</pattern>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <logger name="com.test" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="GELF"/>
  </logger>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
  </root>

</configuration>
```

I need to add an application_version in the  in logback but I cannot get the version trying different things through the process.

First I tried using this options

- application_version=${version}, the application runs but the logger prints version_IS_UNDEFINED
- application_version=${project.version}, the application runs but the logger prints project.version_IS_UNDEFINED
- application_version=@version@, the application runs but the logger prints @version@
- application_version=@project.version@, the application runs but the logger prints @project.version@

Then I added:

```
processResources {
    filesMatching('application.properties') {
        expand(project.properties)
    }
}
```

to the child-project build.gradle and I got this error:

> Missing property (COMPUTERNAME) for Groovy template expansion. Defined
> keys [parent, classLoaderScope, configurations, plugins, objects,
> logger, rootDir, projectRegistry, path, testResultsDirName,
> targetCompatibility, java, normalization, bootJar, childProjects, jar,
> state, processResources, serviceRegistryFactory, tasks, ext,
> projectDir, dependencyLocking, projectEvaluationBroadcaster,
> dependencyManagement, projectPath, module, inheritedScope,
> nexusBuilderUsername, version, script, dependencies,
> processTestResources, webAppDir, extensions, modelRegistry, install,
> projectEvaluator, nexusBuilderUserPassword, projectConfigurator,
> archivesBaseName, logging, configurationActions, sourceCompatibility,
> status, subprojects, components, displayName, bootWar,
> nexusDeployerUsername, parentIdentifier, testClasses,
> antBuilderFactory, out, standardOutputCapture, docsDir,
> compileTestGroovy, defaultTasks, nexusRepo, buildScriptSource,
> autoTargetJvmDisabled, reportsDir, sonarqube, baseClassLoaderScope,
> services, assemble, gradle, distsDirName, buildFile, depth,
> mutationState, docsDirName, testResultsDir, buildDir,
> scriptHandlerFactory, deferredProjectConfiguration, project,
> conf2ScopeMappings, groovyRuntime, repositories,
> nexusDeployerUserPassword, scriptPluginFactory, resourceLoader,
> testReportDir, compileGroovy, mavenPomDir, group, artifacts, test,
> configurationTargetIdentifier, compileJava, check, webAppDirName,
> fileResolver, name, testReportDirName, buildscript, springBoot,
> processOperations, asDynamicObject, publicType, classes, identityPath,
> description, sourceSets, buildPath, fileOperations, pluginManager,
> defaultArtifacts, class, modelSchemaStore, reporting, convention,
> allprojects, ant, war, resources, clean, compileTestJava, layout,
> build, listenerBuildOperationDecorator, libsDir, distsDir,
> uploadArchives, rootProject, libsDirName, properties, providers]

I need help passing the application version from parent gradle.properties to child project logback.xml parametrically. Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly perform a search/replace on your property files during the build. In your case it is failing because Gradle is trying to expand the `${COMPUTERNAME}` reference in your application.properties file. You could solve it by using `filter` instead of `expand`, or by defining `COMPUTERNAME` as a Gradle property with the value "${COMPUTERNAME}" (essentially replacing the value with itself).
However, for including the application version in your logback configuration, there is a (IMHO) more elegant solution.

Spring Boot has a [feature to include build information](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#integrating-with-actuator-build-info) as a property file in your application. In Gradle, you enable it with:

```
springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}
```

The file will be available on the runtime classpath under `META-INF/build-info.properties`. You can then include it as a property source in Logback:

```xml
<configuration>
  <property resource="META-INF/build-info.properties" />
</configuration>
```

The properties in the file can now be referenced like you do already for the Spring properties. Try with `${build.version}` to get the version.

You can also have Spring Boot print out the version in the start-up informational message. But here you have to add it to the MANIFEST.MF file, for instance through:

```
bootJar {
  manifest {
    attributes(
      "Implementation-Title": project.name,
      "Implementation-Version": archiveVersion
    )
  }
}
```

(Note that it will only be printed if you run the actual bootJar file - running the `bootRun` task in Gradle will not do that.)

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 steps here

1. at Build - is processing application.properties
2. at Runtime - logback.xml is initialised from application.properties

you just add the project version in the application.properties
my_version=${project.version}

use my_version in logback.xml

also ${HOSTNAME} instead of ${COMPUTERMNAME}.
see http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html